# Copy emails in monthly archive

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, archive

I must copy emails that are older than 2 days in the monthly archive every day. My problem is if today is 01 or 02 .12.2016 then i must move the emails in the month before the current - 11.2016 . I cant get the code right - if email date is T-2 and email month is not the current then move the emails in the month before current month else move in the current month archive. Any help is welcomed, thank you.

```
Sub Archive_Outlook_eMails_To_Backup_PST_Folder()
    Dim SourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, DestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim MailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim SourceMailBoxName As String, DestMailBoxName As String
    Dim Source_Pst_Folder_Name As String, Dest_Pst_Folder_Name  As String
    Dim MailsCount As Double, NumberOfDays As Double


Dim a As Date
a = Now()

Dim b As String
b = Format(a, "mmmm")

Dim c As String
c = Format(a, "yyyy")

Dim nam As String
nam = "Archive " & b & " " & c


    NumberOfDays = 2

    Source_Pst_Folder_Name = "Inbox"
    Set SourceFolder = Session.Folders("Mailbox - Share ALL").Folders("Inbox").Folders("0.Archive")

    DestMailBoxName = nam
    Dest_Pst_Folder_Name = "0.Archive"
    Set DestFolder = Outlook.Session.Folders(DestMailBoxName).Folders(Dest_Pst_Folder_Name)

    MailsCount = SourceFolder.Items.Count
    While MailsCount > 0


        Set MailItem = SourceFolder.Items.Item(MailsCount)
        If VBA.DateValue(VBA.Now) - VBA.DateValue(MailItem.ReceivedTime) >= NumberOfDays Then
            Dim myCopiedItem As Outlook.MailItem
            Set myCopiedItem = MailItem.Copy
            myCopiedItem.Move DestFolder

        End If

        MailsCount = MailsCount - 1

    Wend

    MsgBox "Mailes in " & Source_Pst_Folder_Name & " are Processed"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility, to check the current date. If it is less than 3, then you go to the specific case:

```
Sub Archive_Outlook_eMails_To_Backup_PST_Folder()
    Dim SourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, DestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim MailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim SourceMailBoxName As String, DestMailBoxName As String
    Dim Source_Pst_Folder_Name As String, Dest_Pst_Folder_Name  As String
    Dim MailsCount As Double, NumberOfDays As Double


Dim a As Date
a = Now()

Dim b As String
b = Format(a, "mmmm")

Dim c As String
c = Format(a, "yyyy")

Dim nam As String
nam = "Archive " & b & " " & c


    NumberOfDays = 2

    Source_Pst_Folder_Name = "Inbox"
    Set SourceFolder = Session.Folders("Mailbox - Share ALL").Folders("Inbox").Folders("0.Archive")

    DestMailBoxName = nam
    Dest_Pst_Folder_Name = "0.Archive"
    Set DestFolder = Outlook.Session.Folders(DestMailBoxName).Folders(Dest_Pst_Folder_Name)

    MailsCount = SourceFolder.Items.Count
    While MailsCount > 0


        Set MailItem = SourceFolder.Items.Item(MailsCount)
        If VBA.DateValue(VBA.Now) - VBA.DateValue(MailItem.ReceivedTime) >= NumberOfDays Then
        Select Case VBA.Now

        Case Is < 3:
            Dim myCopiedItem As Outlook.MailItem
            Set myCopiedItem = MailItem.Copy
            myCopiedItem.Move DestFolder 'The folder should be changed

        Case Else:
            Dim myCopiedItem As Outlook.MailItem
            Set myCopiedItem = MailItem.Copy
            myCopiedItem.Move DestFolder

        End If

        MailsCount = MailsCount - 1

    Wend

    MsgBox "Mailes in " & Source_Pst_Folder_Name & " are Processed"
End Sub
```

Just one small idea for improvement - put all your `dim` on top and not around the code like `Dim myCopiedItem As Outlook.MailItem`. They are initialized anyhow at the very beginning.

Comment: And why should someone do that? _"put all your dim on top and not around the code"_

Comment: This is a good practise in VBA. If it is around the code, you have to think a lot where they are and to look for them. And they all are initialized immediately, it does not matter whether they are in a condition or not.

Comment: Thank you for the help, i put dim for colleagues to know what every module of the code does. It is simpler that way.

Answer (score 1):

How about replacing

```
Dim a As Date
a = Now()

Dim b As String
b = Format(a, "mmmm")

Dim c As String
c = Format(a, "yyyy")

Dim nam As String
nam = "Archive " & b & " " & c
```

by

```
Dim nam As String
nam = "Archive " & format(now()-2, "mmm yyyy")
```

(-2 to get to the correct folder)